# Pass object from Flow to Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

In a Flow, I can retrieve an object and several fields.  Is it possible to pass the object to a Lightning component used in a screen?  I've tried setting up an attribute as Map or Object, and adding the attribute to the Design, but when I attempt to save the Lightning component, I get errors like this:

Error:(1, 1)

> The flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes interface doesn't support these attribute types in the design resource: map.
>
> The forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes interface doesn't support these attribute types in the design resource: map.
>
> The lightning:availableForFlowScreens interface doesn't support these attribute types in the design resource: map.
>
> The flexipage:availableForRecordHome interface doesn't support these attribute types in the design resource: map.

Comment: I answered an almost similar question. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273775/is-it-possible-to-return-a-value-from-a-lightning-component-to-a-flow/273790#273790.
Please go through it and let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer was contained within a comment in this post:  [Is it possible to return a value from a Lightning Component to a flow?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273775/is-it-possible-to-return-a-value-from-a-lightning-component-to-a-flow/273790#273790)

In my Flow, I setup a variable called **orderRecords** of type record, and checked the **Allow multiple values (collection)** property.

Next, I added a **get records** element to my flow.  Itt retrieves all of the order records with the matching **recordId** (passed into the Flow via a variable with that name).  There is only one, but it is stored in **orderRecords** collection variable.

Then in my Lightning component, I defined an **attribute** to receive the collection variable:

```
<aura:attribute name="orderRecords" type="package__Order__c[]" />
```

and included the following in the **design** part:

```
<design:attribute name="orderRecords" label="Order records" description="Only the first one in the collection is used" />
```

And in my component's **init()**, I get the first record in the collection and save that in an attribute:

```
var orderRecords = component.get("v.orderRecords");
var orderObj = null;

if(orderRecords.length > 0) {
    orderObj = orderRecords[0];
    component.set("v.orderObj", orderObj);
}
```

Then, I updated  my flow to pass the orderRecords variable to to the component as an attribute.

Its a bit of work to do things this way, for sure, but does do what I need.  It certainly will be nice whenever SF updates Flows to be able to pass a single record to a component.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, you cannot use a generic Map or Object as an attribute for a flow. You can, however, use an Apex-defined datatype or an sObject type. If these doesn't satisfy your requirement, you can pass the object as a JSON string instead and parse it in the component.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_tips_map.htm

Comment: So I would need a step in the Flow that would convert the retrieved object into a JSon string?  How exactly would that be done?  Via an Apex reference?

Comment: I used a text template variable with hardcoded param names to generate the JSON string and passed it as a param to the flow action. 

Ex:  {"paramName": {!paramValue}}

Comment: I don't believe a Flow variable for a single record can be passed to a Lightning component included in a Flow screen.  It does seem to work for a variable containing a record collection, though.

Answer (score 0):

Flow's new Apex-defined Data Types allows you to define a rich object as an Apex Class and then pass it between Flow and LC's. See https://unofficialsf.com/part-1-manipulate-complex-internet-data-in-flow-without-code/ and https://unofficialsf.com/tdx-session-videobuilding-advanced-flows-with-choices-loops-and-new-apex-defined-types/

Easier than serializing and dealing with JSON, generally.